# Redirect from a Register Form with React Class in v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I'm doing a register form in React using a class and I would like to send the user to another page when the register is correct, the problem is that I haven't find any functional way to make it.

```
.then(data => {
            if(data.error != null) {
                console.log("Error => "+data.error);
            } else {
                //Send the user to the login page
            }
        })
```

This is the part where I would send him to the login page, I have proved with 'useNavigation' and some more, but I can't find the correct way to get it.

Comment: @FabricioB its useNavigate instead of useHistory in react-router v6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since react-router-dom v6 supports only hooks.
For implementing the navigate functionality inside a class-based component, you have to create a HOC and pass the hooks as props.

```
// withRouter.js

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    // any other hooks can be added and passed on
    return (
      <Component
        navigate={navigate}
        {...props}
        />
    );
  };
  
  return Wrapper;
};
```

then on your RegisterForm.jsx you can

```
import {withRouter} from './withRouter';

class RegisterForm extends React.Component{
//...

 yourFunction =() =>{

   .then(data => {
        if(data.error != null) {
           console.log("Error => "+data.error);
         } else {
           //Send the user to the login page
           this.props.navigate('/loginPage'); 
         }
     })
 }
//...

}

export default withRouter(RegisterForm);
```

(https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7256)